# In a simultaneous move game; if a strategy is never the best response, is it dominated?

Tags: game-theory

For example, consider the strategic form game:[image]

In this case, P2 never plays $R$ and P1 never plays $B$. $R$ is dominated by $C$ and $B$ is dominated by playing $T,M$ with respective probabilities $\frac{4}{5},\frac{1}{5}$. Is it always the case that if a strategy is never the best response in a simultaneous move game, then it is dominated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a finite game in strategic form, a strategy of a player is never a best response if and only if it is **strictly** dominated; see Lemma 60.1 in Osborne and Rubinstein, *A course in Game Theory*, 1994.

This lemma implies that an action that is weakly dominated - but not strictly dominated - is a best response to some belief.

(The question does not make clear which notion of dominance is intended.)

Answer (score 0):

It could be that although a certain pure strategy $S$ of player $1$ is not dominated by any of the others, because it would produce the best payoff for one particular pure strategy $T$ of player $2$, strategy $T$ is dominated by other strategies of player $2$ and thus should never be played.  Perhaps for all of player $2$'s pure strategies except $T$, strategy $S$ is worse than strategy $S'$. In this situation an optimal strategy for player $1$ will never include $S$.

Comment: I'm interested in the case were $S$ is never the best response but there is no other pure strategy that is always better than $S$. I.e. can we be sure that we can create a mixed strategy that dominates $S$?

Comment: This answer relates to rationalizability. The OP asked a different question.

Answer (score 0):

I think OP is asking: if a pure strategy is never the best response to another pure strategy, then is it strictly dominated? In this case, the answer is no, it isn't necessarily strictly dominated. I was pondering this question after seeing [this game](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/54879/mixed-strategy-game-theory) on Economics Stack Exchange.

I'll put it here again:

\begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline
&A&B&C\\\hline
A&2,-2&-2,2&0,1\\\hline
B&-2,2&2,-2&0,1\\\hline
C&1,0&1,0&-2,-2\\\hline
\end{array}

In this case, $C$ is never the best response to any pure strategy. However, it isn't strictly dominated since the strategy $\alpha A + (1-\alpha) B$ yields the following payoffs:

\begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline
&A&B&C\\\hline
\alpha A + (1-\alpha) B&4\alpha -2,-4\alpha + 2&-4\alpha + 2,4\alpha -2& 0,1\\\hline
\end{array}

This does not strictly not weakly dominate $C$ for any $\alpha \in [0,1]$.

In relation to Lemma 60.1 in *A course in Game Theory*, the wording is a bit nuanced: An action of a player in a finite strategic game is a never-best response if and only if it is strictly dominated. Definition 59.1 says: An action of player $i$ in a strategic game is a never-best response if it is not a best response to **any belief of player $i$**. In this case, a belief is a probability measure on all other players' actions, so in other words, a pure strategy is only a "never-best response" if for all mixed strategies that the other players can play, there is always a strictly better pure strategy.